# Wait for writing file

Tags: java

I have an small app that write data to file then reading back data,

```
writeData();
readData();
```

but it seems that readData() is executed before WriteData() finished its execution, is there any away to wait for writeData()?

Thank you very much.

Comment: does writeData() spin off a thread to do its work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reentrant lock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) is your best bet. And here's a relevant example.

http://www.carfey.com/blog/java-concurrency-part-2-reentrant-locks/

Comment: Of course you can use `synchronized` but `Locks` are much easier to manage and easy on the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call the flush and close operation on the OutputStream you are using.

```
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

If you are working in the main thread and it still doesn't update, maybe your inspection of the value is delayed? Is it UI-based and you don't update the UI?

The code of your writeData() and readData() operations could give more insights for solving the problem :)